# ASP.NET Core reference connection string in class library project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've created an ASP.NET core 5 Solution and it consists of different projects. The `Startup` class and `DataContext` class are not in the same project so when I'm going to add a new migration on the `Data` project where `DataContext` is located I get the following error.

> Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

It is the structure of the Solution:

[image]

I managed to solve the problem by adding the Startup project's name while adding a new migration, but this way seems annoying to add the project's name every time creating a new migration.

```
dotnet ef migrations add initialcreation -s ..\API\API.csproj
```

No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I also add a new constructor with no parameter in the `DataContext` class and the result was the following error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
> provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring'
> method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider.
> If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Finally, I added the `OnConfiguring` function on `DataContext` and now it is like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() {}
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserPhoto> Photos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("name=DefaultConnection");
        }
    }
}
```

And again I got a new error while creating a new migration:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'DefaultConnection'
> was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named
> connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and
> a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

**UPDATE:**
Here is appsettings.json file:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=database1.db"
},
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Comment: Please show your appsettings.json file.

Comment: @JasonPan I just updated the question.

Comment: Try to use code like `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));`

Comment: @JasonPan I injected IConfiguration in the constructor and add your code but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue, I am also looking for a solution @user3748973

Comment: @fizmhd dotnet ef migrations add initialcreation -s ..\API\API.csproj